# Keep Original value of cell if NULL is selected MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

```
UPDATE  [MyDatabase].[dbo].[Device] 
SET nDeviceTypeID =(SELECT nDeviceTypeID FROM
        DeviceType WHERE sDisplayName =COALESCE (@Role,sDisplayName))
WHERE nDeviceID  IN (SELECT nDeviceID FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[AddressList]
WHERE sNetworkAddress LIKE '%' + @NetworkAddress2 + '%')
```

I have the above update statement to update a cell when parameter is selected. However when parameter is set to null the update doesn't executes which is good, but instead of sending back an error message I would prefer to keep the original value of the cell without executing any updates. Any ideas on what or where am I doing ot wrong ?

**EDIT 1** 
The network address parameter is never null so I only have to make sure that @Role is not NULL. IF @Role is NULL I would like to keep the original value of the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
IF (@Role IS NOT NULL AND @NetworkAddress2 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN

UPDATE  [MyDatabase].[dbo].[Device] 
SET nDeviceTypeID =(SELECT nDeviceTypeID FROM
        DeviceType WHERE sDisplayName =COALESCE (@Role,sDisplayName))
WHERE nDeviceID  IN (SELECT nDeviceID FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[AddressList]
WHERE sNetworkAddress LIKE '%' + @NetworkAddress2 + '%')

END
```

Comment: but in this case if parameter Role is left as default which is set to NULL then the update will absolutely not execute at all right?

Comment: Right , If Role is null then update will not work even if you not pass Role parameter and you have set default NULL then also Update will not work. 
Is this answer helpful to you ?

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved is I used the help from @Anu
This is how my code runs now:

```
IF(@Role IS NULL AND @Role != 'NULL')
BEGIN ...
```

Comment: thanks, farkiba please also handle empty string value , if empty string come then convert into NULL.

Comment: @Anu Could you give any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the last line with

```
WHERE (@NetworkAddress2 IS NOT NULL OR sNetworkAddress LIKE '%' + @NetworkAddress2 + '%'))
```

This will select from `[MyDatabase].[dbo].[AddressList]` only if `@NetworkAddress2` is not `NULL`.

Comment: Hey :) Thanks for your answer, however the problem is not with the network address but rather the <@Role>. Since <@Role> gets the value from a dropdown list. The default value for the DDL is set to NULL and thats where I get the problem. If <@Role> is NULL then the row shouldnt change value